# Derive a class from JointCollection

Tags: c#, kinect, derived-class

I want to **derive** a class from `Microsoft.Kinect.JointCollection` class.

```
public class Derived : JointCollection 
{
    public string NewItem;

    public Derived ()
    {

    }
}
```

### Error:

```
The type 'Microsoft.Kinect.JointCollection' has no constructors defined.
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Base class objects are always constructed before any deriving class.
>   Thus the constructor for the base class is executed before the
>   constructor of the derived class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

The `Microsoft.Kinect.JointCollection` class does not contain a public constructor [[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.jointcollection_members.aspx)] so whenever you attempt to instantiante `Derived` it fails because a public constructor is not available on the base class.

You could consider wrapping the `JointCollection` class with your derived class and providing the appropriate methods to access it in `Derived` that do little more than call methods on `JointCollection` directly.

Comment: How can I provide the following property?

`Derived derived = new Derived();
int dummy = derived["foo"];`

What is the keyword for this?

Comment: It has been a while since I have done this sort of thing so this may not be exactly right but I think you can use an indexer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx `public int this[string index]{ /* get and set accessors */ }`

Answer (score 1):

I think that [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z6fxc01.aspx) means the class only has an internal constructor defined, so you cannot instantiate it from a different assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to derive from calss that was explicitly designed to prohibit this (which can be done by making all constructors internal/private for expample).

Solution: don't do that. Without information why you want to do that it is hard to offer alternatives.